# PHP/Js chat system

Tags: javascript, php

For some reason my chat system isn't sending messages & I can't find what I'm doing wrong. I have the chat 'room' made on my php webpage, but messages won't send.

When I remove my DB password I get errors on the page, so I know it's halfway working, I guess. I also know I have a `#` on the form action.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Blog - Chat</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/blog/CSS3/chat.css"  type="text/css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="C:\\xampp\htdocs\blog\Chat\Javascript\chat.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h3> Welcome <?php print $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>! </h3>
    <div class="chat">
    <div class="chat-status">Status: <span>Idle</span></div>
    <div class="chat-messages"></div>
    <textarea class="chat-textarea" placeholder="Type your message"></textarea> 
    <form action="#" onSubmit ='return false;' id="chatForm">
    <input type="hidden" id="username" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>"/>
    <input type="submit" id="sbutton" name="submit" value="Send"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

sendchat.php

```
$con = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=chat','root','');

if(isset($_POST['text']) && isset($_POST['username']))
{
    $text= strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['text']));
    $username= strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['username']));

     if(!empty($text) && !empty($username))
    {
        $insert = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO messages VALUES('','".$username."','".$text."')");
        $insert->execute();

        echo "<li class='cm'><b>".ucwords($username)."</b> - ".$text."</li>";
    }
}
```

This is my js file

```
$(function(){
  $(document).on('submit','#chatForm',function(){
    var text = $.trim($("#text").val());
    var username = $.trim($("#username").val());

    if(text != "" && username != ""){
        $.post('sendchat.php',{text: text, username: username},function(data){
            $(".chat-messages").append(data);
        });
    }else{
        alert("Data missing");
    }
});

function getMessages(){
    $.get('getmessages.php',function(data){
        $(".chat-messages").php(data);
    });
}

setInterval(function(){
    getMessages();
},500);     });
```

getmessages.php

```
$con = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=chat','root','');

$query = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM messages");
$query->execute();

//Fetch
while($fetch = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
$username = $fetch['username'];
$message = $fetch['message'];

echo "<li class='cm'><b>".ucwords($username)."</b> - ".$message."</li>";
}
```

Comment: What are the errors? Do you have error_reporting enabled?

Comment: Why `VALUES('',` ? Do you forget to tell what fields you want insert in your table ?

Comment: No errors, my message just won't send in the chat.

Comment: Do you have that row recorded in your table ?

Comment: You may want to look into socket.io to handle your messaging. It's all in real-time - http://socket.io/demos/chat/ And for the record, rather than placing the `$_SESSION['user_id']` in a hidden form field, you'd be better off just calling that from `sendchat.php`. As it stands at the moment anyone could modify the value of your hidden form field to be any number they like, meaning your script would think they are someone else.

Comment: @J Young Actually, the user_id doesn't refer to the ID. It's the username, I have that setup in a different file.

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript is listening out for the form to be submitted:

```
$(document).on('submit','#chatForm',function(){
```

But in the form you're returning `false` as soon as it's submitted, so your JavaScript wont be triggered.

```
<form action="#" onSubmit ='return false;' id="chatForm">
```

You need to remove the onSubmit code from your form and add this to your JavaScript:

```
$(this).preventDefault();
```

and then at the end of the function you return false. Your whole function should look like this:

```
$(document).on('submit','#chatForm',function(){
    $(this).preventDefault();
    var text = $.trim($("#text").val());
    var username = $.trim($("#username").val());

    if(text != "" && username != ""){
        $.post('sendchat.php',{text: text, username: username},function(data){
            $(".chat-messages").append(data);
        });
    } else {
        alert("Data missing");
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: *This did send my message, but not on the chat screen or in my DB. It just goes away.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using PDO library, you need to set your insert statement as below:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO messages (field1,field2) VALUES (:username,:msg_text)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':username'=>$username,':msg_text'=>$text));
```